# Akka - Readable state

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Hi so I know that shared state is highly discouraged in Akka, but I have the following dilema:

I have one actor managing many child actors. The child actors all write onto their own state. But the managing actors might issue different messages to its children depending on their states and relations to each other. So I need a state that is readable by the managing actor and writable by the child actor. Are there any good patterns/practices for this kind of use case?

Thanks!

Comment: How about doing inversion of control? Instead of the parent actor viewing the internal state of each child, have the children send acknowledges to the parent once their state changes and they require new messages.

Comment: I did think about having a version of the states in the parent that is updated by the children. But then wouldn't having 2 versions of the same state kind of inefficient?

Comment: Why move the state to the parent?

Comment: The parent is basically a collision detector and the children are bodies. The parent needs to know the relations between the children's positions to issue commands as needed.

Comment: How about having the children send messages to the parent about their updated status and have the parent issue commands based on that?

Comment: I guess for some reason that seemed messy as I would have a state in the children and another copy in the parent. But maybe I should simply think of the children as being something that is stateless and just purely does the computation from one state to the next? Or is having multiple copies of the state floating around part of the design?

Comment: From my (limited) Akka experience, stateless is by far the easiest to deal with. I would imagine that querying children for state would very soon become a mess, especially if you factor in asynchronous message nature and possibility of message loss in a distributed environment.

Comment: Having children send in periodic updates and parent recompute state upon them seems the logical solution. But of course it places natural limitations upon state size (available memory) and number of processed messages (one actor bottleneck).

Comment: To me it seems collision detection cannot work without some form of shared state. In the end, it's the particles that occupy or "own" a fraction of the "global resource of space". I don't know much about collision detection but you probably will want some division of space to make it efficient (spatial partitioning). If you want to implement that with actors, each partition could be an actor, and each particle actor registers and unregisters it's position with its current partition (maybe similar to how planes register with air traffic control).

Comment: Thanks I'll probably use a combination of spatial partitioning and some calculation actors that calculate the next state given an initial state.